# Change CSS class after interval with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with content and I want to change a class name to make the div visible. I have an interval and when expired it should change to `display: yes` and it should appear, but it is not working. If I set to disappear after 4 second the script runs correctly, but when I want it to appear it fails.

```js
var $post = $(".hide");
setInterval(function() {
  $post.toggleClass("show");
}, 4000);
```

```css
.show {
  display: yes;
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide">
  text
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/istvan1026/g1cvttnd/1/

Comment: Relevant code belongs directly into your question, not only on external sites. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of answers here that rewrite your code to make it work, but not much explanation of *why* your code didn't work.

First the easy part: `display: yes` isn't a thing; allowed values for `display` include `block`, `inline`, and `none`. (As well as a couple dozen other values, but not "yes".)

Correcting that "show" class to use `display: block` instead of `display: yes` doesn't solve the problem on its own, though: your div has the class "hide", and you're toggling the class "show" on and off (without removing the "hide" class.)  Therefore the two toggle states are "hide" or "show hide" (both classes together).

And because the "hide" class is after the "show" class in the CSS, it takes precedence, so when both classes are on the same element the "hide" class wins.

There are several different ways to solve this:  you could not use the "show" class at all, and just toggle the "hide" class on and off. Or you could toggle both classes simultaneously:

```
$post.toggleClass("show hide");
// Or use $post.toggleClass("show").toggleClass("hide");  same thing
```

Since the initial state of the div is "hide" (by itself), toggling both show and hide classes together would mean the next state would be "show" (by itself), then back to "hide" (by itself.)

A couple of other minor points:

- As mentioned in @rbester's answer, it might be safer to use an explicit identifier on the div, instead of capturing it using the same classname you'll later be toggling on and off.  It works okay in your code because you're capturing the div in the variable `$post`, but it'd be easy to later on accidentally try to refer to it as `$('.hide')` inside the `setInterval` loop, which wouldn't always match the element you want.
- It's not necessary to set both `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` to hide the element.  Either one on its own will hide the element (though not exactly the same way. Setting `visibility:hidden` will hide the element but still leaves space for it in the layout. `display:none` removes it from the layout completely.  In most situations `display:none` is what you want.)

Comment: Don't forget `inline-block` :)

Comment: That's why I said 'include' :)   I'll clarify the answer though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `toggleClass`, it should be fine:

```js
var post = $("#text");
setInterval(function(){
    post.removeClass("hide");
    post.addClass("show");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.show {
    display: inline;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" class="hide">
 text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to toggle the `hide` class, as in:

```
var $post = $(".hide");
setInterval(function(){
    $post.toggleClass("show");
    $post.toggleClass("hide");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the display property cannot have 'yes'. It can be 'block', 'inline', 'none' etc.

Second, using the identifier $(".hide") is a problem, since that's the class you are toggling.

You do not need a .show class. Simply use:

html:

```
<div class="myDiv hide">
    text
</div>
```

js:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".myDiv").toggleClass("hide");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Using `$('.hide')` as the identifier works in his code, because he's capturing it in the variable `$post` instead of referring to it by classname inside the setinterval. You're right that it's potentially confusing, though, an explicit identifier would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $post = $(".hide");

setInterval(function(){
     $post.toggleClass('hide');
}, 4000);
```

Css

```
.hide{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hello = $(".hide");
setInterval(function(){ 
    hello.removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
}, 4000);
```

```css
.show{
    
    visibility: visible;
}


.hide{
 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide">
 text
</div>
```

Hope,this solves your problem.

Comment: To make you better understand what you did wrong `yes` is not a legal value for the `display` a correct value would be `block`,  `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @KarimCossutti Your comment belongs on the original question, not this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using setInterval.

If you want to toggle, that is, appear and disappear the div alternately then use

```
$("div").toggleClass("hide");
```

If you only want to make it appear then use

```
$("div").removeClass("hide");
```

js:

```
setInterval(function(){
    //to toggle
    $("div").toggleClass("hide");

    //to only make it appear
    $("div").removeClass("hide");
}, 4000);
```

html:

```
<div class="hide">text</div>
```

css:

```
.hide{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here's an example

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $("div").toggleClass("hide");
}, 4000);
```

```css
.hide{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide">
 text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option for you to explore is the option of using jQuery's built in functions such as .hide(), .show() and .toggle()

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/basics/